# Apacite for in proceedings

Tags: bibtex, apa-style

I am using [`apacite`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/apacite) to format inproceedings entries, and from what I read, in APA style the volume and pages should be separated by commas, like this:

```
Author, A. A., & Author, B. B. (1996). Title of journal article: Subtitle of journal article. Title of journal, volume number, first page-last page.
```

Instead, apacite puts the volume and page in brackets:
IEEE International Conference on Systems, Man and Cybernetics, (Vol. 1, p. 317-322).

I thought `apacite` formats according to the APA standard, yet in this case it doesn't seem so. Is there a way to change this behavior?

Answer (score 2):

The default behaviour of `apacite` is what you desire; see an example below. I suspect another package that you load in your code interacts with `apacite` in some fashion.

However, without seeing a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228), the cause of the problem is difficult to figure out. Please post a MWE, and I will refine my answer to help you further.

---

[image]

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{mylib.bib}
@ARTICLE{Vickrey1961,
AUTHOR = {W. Vickrey},
TITLE = {Counterspeculation, auctions and sealed tenders},
JOURNAL = {Journal of Finance},
YEAR = {1961},
volume = {16},
pages = {8--37},
} 
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\citeA{Vickrey1961} showed that incentive compatibility is guaranteed if the auction winner has to pay the second highest price.

\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{mylib}

\end{document}
```